# Grabbing city names and numbers from a CSV file

Tags: php, regex, csv

I've got information that is imported from a CSV file that my site grabs every day with PHP. I'm just learning RegEx so I'm able to do what I need to do but am looking to get more efficient with my coding.

Some of example of the kinds of strings that would come in would be:

```
15 SE NORFOLK
5 NNE OAKLAND
1 S LOS ANGELES
1 NW SACRAMENTO
BOSTON
```

It's basically numbers then directional letters then city name. Sometimes there aren't numbers and letters so I'm checking to see first and then just deleting them with `preg_replace` if there are (I just need the city name).

Here's the expression I have that works:

```
$location = preg_replace('/^[\d]+[\s]+[a-zA-z]+[\s]/', '', $string);
```

I know with regex there are a bunch of different ways to different things so I'm curious if there's a more efficient way to do what I'm doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leave out the square brackets:

```
^\d+\s+[A-Z]+\s+
```

Square brackets are used for "character classes", like

```
[A-Z]
```

which matches exactly one letter out of the range A to Z.

`\d` already is a class: all the numbers.

Comment: Ok great! Thanks. I'm just learning, every little bit helps.

Answer (score 1):

Because you know that the City is always the last word of the line, you could always just look for that by doing something like :

```
$location = preg_replace('(\S*\s)*([a-zA-Z]+)(\s*$)', '\2', $string);
```

group 1: any non whitespace(\S) followed by a whitespace(\s) 0 or more times.
         (in your case up to 2)

group2: any letter 1 or more times (the city name)

group3: any number of spaces followed by the end of the line

**note: IDK anything about PHP, so the way you need to reference the group names may be slightly different**